# Can I pass text file as an argument in a main function in C?

Tags: c, arguments

I am wondering if I could pass file as an argument in a main function? I mean not a name of the file but file itself.

Comment: This doesn't really make sense...

Comment: Not directly, but by redirecting the input such as `myprog <test.dat`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not unless something external (e.g. a bash script) reads in the file and adds it as an argument.  If there is a binary 0 in the file, that would be interpreted as the end of string.

You can achieve something similar using [input redirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29), where the contents of a file is redirected to stdin, e.g.

```
myprogram < myTextFile
```

You would then be able to read the contents of the file by reading from stdin.

Answer (score 0):

You could, as long as there's no 0 bytes in the file.

Also, you shouldn't.

If you want to know how to do that, it depends on the operating system.